# Градиентная рамка

Tags: html, css, border

Надо добиться такого результата: https://prnt.sc/z3q7ti

Накидал такой код:

```css
.box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  
}

.title {
  width: 50%;
  height: 150px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: blue;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 50px 50px 50px 150px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 28px;
  clip-path: polygon(10% 0, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="title">
    Lorem ipsum dolor.
  </div>
</div>
```

Мне нужно только рамка, остальное сделаю

Comment: Ну почему картинка то на "левом" хостинге? Её же можно сразу в вопрос вставить.

Answer (score 3):

Если я правильно понимаю поставленную задачу по картинке, то например можно это сделать так:

```css
.box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
}

.title {
  width: 50%;
  height: 150px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 50px 50px 50px 150px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 28px;
  clip-path: polygon(10% 0, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, white 0%, transparent 70%);
}

.title:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: calc(100% - 3px);
  height: calc(100% - 3px);
  background-color: blue;
  clip-path: polygon(10% 0, 100% 0%, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
}

.title>div {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 80%;
  height: 90%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="title">
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Не вижу смысла использовать `clip-path`, достаточно обычного `transform: skew();`.

Самый хитрый элемент здесь - это верхняя граница, которая растворяется с помощью радиального градиента, и потому, имеет необычную форму.

```css
body { margin: 0; }

.box {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: flex-end;
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9kuJ.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.title {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  height: 150px;
  width: calc(100% - 130px);
  padding: 50px 50px 50px 150px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 28px;
  color: #fff;
}
.title::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -8px;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  height: calc(100% + 8px);
  width: calc(110% + 100px);
  transform-origin: top left;
  transform: skewx(326deg);
  background-image: radial-gradient( farthest-side at 0% 0%, #ffff 30%, #fff0 45%), linear-gradient(#ffff, #ffff), linear-gradient(#88f8, #88f8);
  background-position: 0% 0px, 0% 0%, 10px 8px;
  background-size: 75% 7px, 3px 100%, 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="title">
    Lorem ipsum dolor.
  </div>
</div>
```